# How to open a XML from Enterprise Architect without spending money?

Tags: diagrams, enterprise-architect

Someone with EA has saved/exported a set of xml files. I want to open those files to see the diagrams, but I don't know a free tool that would do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [EA Viewer](http://www.sparxsystems.eu/enterprisearchitect/ea-lite-edition/) (free, a read-only version of EA) can help you view those files.

Comment: Apparently, it is (no longer?) possible to read *.xml files with the AELite